# CDI: pass through qualifier from one injection point to the other

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, qualifiers

I'd like to kind of pass-through a qualifier annotation using CDI. With that I mean that I'd want to add a qualifier to an injection point with that qualifier not being applied directly for the "first-level" injection target (because there is only one implementation for this) but a field within ("2nd level") the injected EJB. Is this possible with CDI? Does it maybe already work out-of-the-box?

It should look similar to:

```
@Stateless
public class MyFirstLevelEJB {

@Inject
//this guy has different Implementations with qualifiers, I want to use the qualifier here
private CDIBean2ndLevel myCDIBean;

}

2nd EJB:
@Stateless
public class My2ndLevelEJB {

@Inject
@AlternativeImplementation //this is the qualifier which I want to apply for CDIBean2ndLevel
MyFirstLevelEJB anInjectedEBJ; 
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: As long as the classes are properly annotated with those qualifiers, this should work fine.

Comment: so you are saying that the qualifier will be passed/visible to the fields of MyFirstLevelEJB and will pick the appropriate Impl even if I annotate the injection point OUTSIDE of MyFirstLevelEJB? I will give it a try...

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The injection point and impl need to share qualifiers in order to resolve those dependencies.

Comment: Sadly this is not possible with CDI at the moment, though I often had situations where I needed something like this. In some circumstances (not when injecting EJBs as you do) you can partly work around this by using producer methods with parameters to create beans.