# How can the class that @Injects a @Dependent class pass information to its constructor?

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, qualifiers

My problem is probably best explained with some sample code:

```
@Named
public class Search {
    @Inject @Select(Type.SEARCH)
    private Criteria criteria;
}

@Named
public class Selection {
    @Inject @Select(Type.SELECTION)
    private Criteria criteria;
}

public class Criteria {
    private final List<Selection> statics;
    private final List<Selection> choosables;

    @Inject
    public Criteria(
            @Any Instance<List<Selection>> statics,
            @Select(Type.CHOOSABLE) List<Selection> choosables,
            InjectionPoint ip) {
        Select sel = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Select.class);
        this.statics = cloneList(statics.select(sel).get());
        choosables = cloneList(choosables);
    }
}
```

The idea is that `Criteria` has all the logic to deal with lists of `Selection` objects, but the actual lists to manage vary depending on the user of the `Criteria` class. As it stands, Weld complains about being unable find a class with the matching qualifiers, since `Criteria` isn't annotated `@Select`. So - can I make `Criteria` eligible for injection no matter the `@Select` qualifier? Or is there another way to pass that piece of information to the `Criteria` class?

**Edit:** turns out, the question has already been asked in a similar form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18013305/785663).

Comment: Not sure tot totally understand your use case. What you want is a `Criteria` bean that could be injected for whatever qualifier on InjectionPoint. Is that it ? Are you using CDI 1.0 or 1.1 ?

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand yeah, that would help. Basically, I'd use this to simulate "pass an argument to the constructor" to switch the data source that `Criteria` uses. I'm using Wildfly-8.Beta1, so this is CDI-1.1.